# Is it possible to trick Javascript's instanceof operator without access to the class definition?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, scope

I have a very niche problem I'm trying to solve. I am building a Chrome extension content script, which means I have limited access to the internals of any scripts running on the page.

I found an accessible globally-defined function on the page I am running my content script that I can pass an object to in order to trigger behavior I want. I was originally going to just reverse engineer the content of the object to pass in an object with the proper shape the function expects. However, upon inspecting the logic of that function, I found that it uses `instanceof` as a qualifier for when to handle the event in a particular way, meaning it can't just be an anonymous object. Unfortunately, the class definition is created in a function scope within that script, which means, as far as I know, I cannot instantiate a new instance of the class that would be needed in order for `instanceof` to evaluate to true.

Here is a minimum code example to illustrate the situation:

```js
// Script running on the page

(function() {
  var SomeClass = function() {
    // ...
  }

  window.accessibleFunction = (event) => {
    if (event instanceof SomeClass) {
      // Do stuff I want the application to do
    }
  }
})()
```

I'd like to be able to call `window.accessibleFunction` and pass in the event to then hit the logic within the `instanceof` check, but because `SomeClass` is defined in the function scope, I can't just do `new SomeClass()`.

So, my question is, is there some way I can pass an object into `window.accessibleFunction` such that it passes the `instanceof` check without actually being able to create a real instance of SomeClass? In other words, can I somehow trick `instanceof`?

Alternatively, is there some way I can expose SomeClass to the global scope so that my extension's content script can access it? I'm guessing not, but figure it's worth asking if anyone has ideas.

Comment: If the object you are passing is not an instance of `SomeClass`, the code inside `window.accessibleFunction` is likely to fail when it tries to invoke a method of `SomeClass`.

Comment: See if SomeClass or its *instance* is exposed elsewhere so you can get its reference via prototype.

Comment: The script should also contain some code that instantiates a `SomeClass` object and passes it to `window.accessibleFunction`. Can you trigger that? That's the way to get a hand onto the class.

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone. I had looked for all instances of the application creating SomeClass to see if I could use those, but there were no accessible functions I could utilize. I did come up with a sort of ridiculous solution where I replace accessibleFunction with a wrapper function that captures one of the events and places it on the window object. Then, I can manually trigger a click event that eventually invokes that function, allowing my content script to get an instance of SomeClass, which it can use to make a new SomeClass instance. Not a pretty solution but it works!

Comment: @TechyTech Yes, that's what I meant. It might be easier (and cleaner) to inject a `"window.SomeClass = SomeClass;"` into the code of the script, but I don't know enough about chrome extensions to say how such interception might work

Comment: @Bergi Yeah I thought about that idea too but I don’t think it’s possible for me to write code outside the scope of that function and have it somehow execute as if it were in that scope, which is what would need to happen in order for it to have access to SomeClass. I’ll post my solution shortly to illustrate what exactly I ended up doing.

Comment: I did not mean by executing code in a content script, but rather by [intercepting the code of the IIFE itself](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/)

Comment: Ohhh, well that is intriguing. I will definitely play around with this and see if it’s something that can be done!

Comment: @Bergi so it seems like it's not possible due to the restrictions of the new(ish) Manifest v3 for browser extensions, which removes the ability to programmatically intercept, analyze, and modify web requests. It's one of the main gripes people have with V3. Definitely was an interesting idea though!

Answer (score 0):

To answer my top-level question: it appears the answer is **no**, you cannot trick `instanceof` into evaluating to true without actually constructing an instance of the class it is checking against.

Here is the solution I ended up going with. It is not pretty, but it does work for my particular use case:

**Setup**

```js
// Hold reference to the original function
window.originalAccessbileFunction = window.accessibleFunction;

// Replace accessibleFunction with a wrapper that captures an instance of SomeClass and places it on window.
window.accessibleFunction = (someClassInstance) => {
  window.someClassInstance = someClassInstance;

  return window.originalAccessibleFunction(someClassInstance);
}

// Trigger an event that results in the application calling window.accessibleFunction
triggerAccessibleFunctionEvent()
```

**Using accessibleFunction**

```js
// Create a new instance of SomeClass
let newSomeClassInstance = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(window.someClassInstance));

// Modify the new instance to have the correct object shape/properties
newSomeClassInstance.exampleProperty = 5;

// Call accessibleFunction with the expected SomeClass instance
window.accessibleFunction(newSomeClassInstance);
```

It is a somewhat laborious solution, but it does manage to work.